# EasyMock : static method and 'missing behavior definition for the preceding method call'?

Tags: easymock

I have the following core class MessagesUtil, which returns a message string from a specific bundle based on a locale - all the getMessage() methods are static

```
public class MessagesUtil { ..

    public static String getMessage(HttpServletRequest request, String key, String bundle) {
        MessageResources resources = (MessageResources)request.getAttribute(bundle);
        String message = resources.getMessage((Locale)request.getSession().getAttribute("org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE"), key);
        return message;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a unit test which coverage a business class which calls the MessageUtils object. The same test code below shows how i'm mocking the request and session, to return the MessageResources and then specific message keys

```
import com.infonova.easymock.annotation.Mock;
import org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.Locale;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;

public class MappingsUtilsEasyMockTest {

    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Mock
    private HttpSession session;

    @Mock
    private MessageResources messageResources;

    @Test
    public void mockMessagesUtilTests() {

        String key = "ordermanagement.error.general";

        expect(request.getAttribute("CustomerManagementResources")).andReturn(messageResources);
        // the locale
        Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        expect(session.getAttribute("org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE")).andReturn(locale);
        // the locale specific String from the message Resource
        expect(messageResources.getMessage(locale, key)).andReturn("this_is_the_result");

        Assert.assertEquals(MessagesUtil.getMessage(
                        request, key, CustomerManagementConstants.BUNDLE_NAME),
                "this_is_the_result");
    }
}
```

I get this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
HttpServletRequest.getAttribute("CustomerManagementResources")
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:42)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getSession(Unknown Source)
```

but i am setting the 'getAttribute("CustomerManagementResources")' field in the test setup.

Note - I have tried adding

```
replay();
```

before i call the target method but there is no difference.

Answer (score 4):

So after some work, the EasyMock exception message which says 'preceding' can be considered to mean 'next' method call. In my case the

```
(Locale)request.getSession()
```

was the next call my the class i was looking to mock. Add this expect to my test resolved the issue

```
expect(request.getSession()).andReturn(session).anyTimes();
```